# My google play is logged in a different E-mail than my google account

Tags: google-play-store, accounts

For some reason my google play is under some other E-mail but my google account it still signed in.. So when I tried to purchase an app it made me add my card info and it added it to this other E-mail. When I try to remove it I am sent to google where I am logged in... So how do I remove my card from this other persons google play account? I have no idea who this is so I cant even ask for them to do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you took the old one off.

If not, just go onto the store, tap the side menu icon, tap the down arrow above the options, and switch account.Then delete it from the accounts menu in settings.

If you did take it off:

Take off *every* account, and clear the data, cache and force stop the play store. If you must, uninstall its updates. Then re-add the needed account.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between the Google accounts you have in your phone, from the left menu bar in Google Play. Tap the arrow icon next to the email address (old one) and select the new one.

If you do not use that old account in your phone anymore, try removing that from your Settings > Accounts. That should make your Play Store to ask you which Google Account you want to use with it, the next time you start it.